# getting no value from fatching mysql data using mysql_fetch_array($result) function

Tags: php, mysql

i am getting no of rows of `$result>0`  but number of rows `$row is zero` . the `$row` is not get any output from `fetch()` function.  can anyone explain this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM resume";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


 if(is_null($result))
  {
   $pdf->Cell(10, 6, 'NAdjdnjfjkdnME', 1, 5, 'L', 1);   // to check reult                 value

}
//initialize counter
$i = 0;

//Set maximum rows per page
$max = 25;

//Set Row Height
$row_height = 6;
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if(is_null($row))
   {
      $pdf->Cell(20, 32, 'NAdjd', 3, 2, 'L', 1);

   }

   if (mysqli_num_rows($row) ==0) {
         $pdf->Cell(10, 32, '00', 3, 2, 'L', 1);   // to check row value  // here is error

}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  if(!is_null($row))
   {
      $pdf->Cell(100, 12, 'NAdjd', 1, 0, 'L', 1);

   }
```

Comment: you want to say that  no record in `resume` table but it shows that records are there?

Comment: You're mixing MySQL and MySQLi, that will not work.

Comment: ohhkay ..  i got the point .. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are your errors:

1. `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);` should be changed to `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);`
2. `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))` should change to `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))`
3. `if (mysqli_num_rows($row) ==0)` should change to if `(mysqli_num_rows($result) ==0)`

And please close the while loop with an ending `}` if you didn't actually include it.

Hope your problem is solved..

Answer (score -1):

Try to use count() instead of is_null(). Just do it like this:

```
if(count($row) != 0) {

}
```

if you want to make sure there are records, or

```
if(count($row) == 0) {

}
```

if you want to make sure that there are no records. You can probably use the strict equality (===) as well. Hope this helps!